# two column belong to association with different name rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a result table with winner and loser column, these are related with the user table:

```
   #Result controller
   @results = Result.includes(:user).all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)

   #result model
   class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
   end

   #user model
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :result
   end
```

how i do to make this possible?

```
   <td><%= result.user.winner %></td>
   <td><%= result.user.loser %></td>
```

Comment: is It right condition

Comment: You need to define associations in the user model for winner and loser if you want to access their records in the manner you requested. However, I'd recommend that you refine your associations and edit your answer with your attempt at doing this first. Are you sure each user should have a winner and loser association when a user can have many results? It sounds wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like... because if you find result.user => it will give you a user details n user does not have single result so you cannot check it with user.

```
<td><%= result.winner == true ? "User Is Winner" : "User Is Looser " %></td>`
```